# APIなどを使用し、Google Vault からメールデータ取得したい

Tags: google-api

Google Vault からメールデータを抽出またはダウンロードする
プログラムを開発することは可能でしょうか。
公開されているAPIにはそのようなAPIは存在しないように見えます。

宜しくお願いいたします。

https://developers.google.com/vault/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

半年前から取得できるようになっています。
https://developers.google.com/vault/guides/exports

Answer (score 0):

使ったことは無いですがこれなんかどうです？
https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/

Comment: 案件情報やクエリ情報等は取れるのですが、メール情報を抽出するようなAPIは存在しないように見えます。
（もちろんAPIはキックしてみました）